# Can i set dynamic step size on stepped line chart in chart.js?

Tags: charts, chart.js

In chart.js, the x-axis of the stepped line chart are fixed.
for example, I want to displays when x is less than 2, y is 10, x is between 2 and 10, y is 20, x is larger than 10, y is 5.

How can i do this with chart.js?

Comment: I read your question several times but I still don't understand what you're looking for. Please try to rephrase/structure your question and if possible also show the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

By default the closest you can come is by using a logarithmic scale, only downside is you can't choose the tick spacing but it will increase.

The only way to achieve what you want is by writing your own custom axis as described here in the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/axes.html